# Comma separating a list of dictionaries using jinja

Tags: python, dictionary, jinja2

I am trying to add a comma (using jinja) between a list of items which are in an array of dictionaries in python.

I am doing the following:

```
@{@ for row in data.results -@}@
@{{@ row.gene|join(',', attribute='gene')@}}@
@{@ endfor @}@}
```

However, each gene belongs to a dictionary in an array of dictionaries in python, such as

```
'results': [
         {'aminoacidic': u'p.Leu110Val',
          'criterium': u'1000',
          'ensembl': u'rs2301149',
          'gene': u'KCNMB1',
          'hgmd': u'CM078442',
          'nucleotidic': u'c.328C>G'},
         {'aminoacidic': None,
          'criterium': u'1000',
          'ensembl': u'rs13306673',
          'gene': u'SLC12A3',
          'hgmd': None,
          'nucleotidic': u'c.283-54T>C'},
          {'aminoacidic': None,
          'criterium': u'3000',
          'ensembl': u'rs72811418',
          'gene': u'CYBA',
          'hgmd': u'CR073543',
          'nucleotidic': u'c.*-675A>T'}
         ]
```

I would like to have the following output:

```
         blabla in the gene list KCNMB1, SLC12A3, and CYBA.
```

How can I properly add the attribute for an integer.gene in jinja so that I have the genes separated by commas? Is there any easy way to put the "and" word before the last gene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [loop](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#for) variables:

```
{% for result in results %}
  {% if not loop.last %}{{ result.gene }}, {% else %}and {{ result.gene }}.{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively, patch together 2 joins:

```
{{ (results[:results|length-1]|join(", ",attribute="gene"), (results|last).gene | join("and ") }}
```

In this case, we take results without the last item and join it all together with commas (`results[:results|length-1]|join(", ",attribute="gene")`) then join that with the last item.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation and clean solution!

Comment: no problem, out of curiosity, which was your preferred solution?

Comment: I used the first one. It seems easier to understand for someone else that might read my code.